# Hashing using salt on android and iphone

Tags: android, iphone, encryption, message-digest, saltedhash

I am developing an app on both android and iphone which requires encryption of some data.

I want to know is there any way to encrypt data producing same hash on both platform.
I have common salt, just wanted to have same encrypted data output from digest as my server is same for both platform.

I am bit new to iphone so my question would be naive please bear with it.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a standard hashing algoritm like SHA1, and just append your salt to the original string.

Please note the difference between encrypt and hash:

- Encrypting scrambles data in such a way that it is possible to recreate the original data using some kind of key (decrypting).
- Hashing doesn't provide a way to decrypt, because several different inputs may produce the same hash